# A combinatorial expression of Hall-Littlewood polynomials

Tags: rt.representation-theory, symmetric-functions, geometric-representation-theory

This is related to the question [Hall-Littlewood functions and functions on the nilpotent cone](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160131/hall-littlewood-functions-and-functions-on-the-nilpotent-cone), and arises in the construction of Coulomb branches of gauge theories. The motivation is explained at the bottom.

Let us prepare some notation. Let $\lambda$ be a dominant coweight of $GL(N)$, i.e., tuples of (not necessarily positve) integers $\lambda_1\ge\lambda_2\ge\cdots\ge\lambda_N$. We set $|\lambda| = \lambda_1+\dots+\lambda_N$, and define $b_\lambda(t)$ (denoted by $P_{U(N)}(t,\lambda)$ in [1403.0585](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.0585)) by
$$
 \prod_{i\in\mathbb Z} \varphi_{m_i(\lambda)}(t), \qquad 
 \varphi_r(t) = (1-t)(1-t^2)\cdots (1-t^r),
$$
where $m_i(\lambda)$ denotes the number of times $i$ occurs as a part of $\lambda$. This is the inverse of the Poincare polynomial of the classifying space of the stabilizer of $\lambda$ in $GL(N)$ in view of [1601.03586](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.03586).

Let $\lambda^1$, $\lambda^2$, $\dots$, $\lambda^{N-1}$ be dominant coweights of $GL(N-1)$, $GL(N-2)$, $\dots$, $GL(1)$. We define
$
   \Delta(\lambda,\lambda^1,\dots,\lambda^{N-1})
$
by
$$
   \frac12\left( \sum_{j=1}^{N-1} \sum_{i,i'} |\lambda^{j-1}_i - \lambda^{j}_{i'}| \right) - \sum_{j=1}^{N-1} \sum_{i < i'} |\lambda^j_i - \lambda^j_{i'}|,
$$
where $\lambda^0 = \lambda$. We fix $\lambda$ and consider
$$
  H[T_{(1^N)}(SU(N)](t,x_1,\dots,x_N,\lambda) :=
  x_1^{|\lambda|} \sum_{\lambda^1,\lambda^2,\dots,\lambda^{N-1}}
t^{\Delta(\lambda,\lambda^1,\dots,\lambda^{N-1})} 
\times \prod_{j=1}^{N-1} \left(\frac{x_{j+1}}{x_j}\right)^{|\lambda^j|}
 \frac1{b_{\lambda^j}(t)}.
$$
This is the monopole formula in [1403.0585](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.0585) for the special case $\rho=(1^N)$. 
Now [1403.0585](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.0585) claims that
$$
  H[T_{(1^N)}(SU(N)](t,x_1,\dots,x_N,\lambda)
  = t^{\frac{(N-1)|\lambda|}2 - n(\lambda)} R_\lambda(x_1,\dots,x_N;t)
    \prod_{i\neq i'} \frac1{1 - x_i^{-1}x_{i'} t}
$$
where
$$
   n(\lambda) = \sum (i-1)\lambda_i,
$$
$$
   R_\lambda(x_1,\dots,x_N;t) = \sum_{w\in S_N} w\left(
   x_1^{\lambda_1}\cdots x_N^{\lambda_N} \prod_{i<i'} \frac{x_i - tx_{i'}}{x_i-x_{i'}}\right).
$$
As far as I understand, this is checked numerically in many cases, but no rigorous proof is given.

I together with Braverman, Finkelberg am trying to give a geometric proof of this result, but we are wondering whether this is known, or has a purely combinatorial proof.

Here is the motivation. In [1503.03676](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03676) (see also [1601.03586](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.03586)), I conjectured that the space of sections of a line bundle over the cotangent bundle of the flag variety for $SL(N)$ is realized by the Borel-Moore homology of a certain space, whose Poincare polynomial has a combinatorial expression, known as a monopole formula by Cremonesi, et al. Since the former is given by Hall-Littlewood polynomials, we arrive at a combinatorial expression of Hall-Littlewood polynomials as above.

Comment: The paper giving a geometric proof of this formula is available at https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.02112

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple observation (which you probably already know). If you send $t\to0$, then $b_\lambda$ in your formula disappears, and it remains to minimize $\Delta$. The minimum is then achieved on the weights $\lambda^j$ which interlace, i.e. $\lambda^j_i\ge \lambda^{j-1}_i\ge \lambda^j_{i-1}$, where I identified $\lambda$ with $\lambda^N$ instead of $\lambda^0$. For the interlacing weights the factor $t^\Delta$ disappears and what is left is the standard combinatorial formula for Schur polynomials.

By the way, doing this computation carefully in $N=2$ case, I feel that there might be a misprint in powers of $t$. Namely, we have $\lambda_1\ge \lambda_2$ and we sum over all $n$ satisfying $\lambda_1\ge n \ge \lambda_2$. Then $t^\Delta=t^{(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)/2}$, and so this is a bit different from the prefactor $t^{N(N-1)/2-n(\lambda)}$, which your formula suggests. So something like additional $t^{|\lambda|/2}$ factor is missing in this case

Comment: Thank you very much for a remark.

The prefactor was wrong as you said. It should be $t^{\frac{(N-1)|\lambda|}2 - n(\lambda)}$. (The original paper is correct. I made a mistake.)

Your condition means $\lambda$, $\lambda^1$, $\dots$, $\lambda^{N-1}$ form a Gelfand-Tsetlin pattern. (I think the condition is $\lambda^{j-1}_i \ge \lambda^j_i \ge \lambda^{j-1}_{i-1}$.)

Comment: Maybe this suggests that there is a combinatorial proof using the Gessel-Viennot trick.